# Concatening rows to columns in SQL Query issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, rows, for-xml-path

I'm having an issue with the below query result. I want to  concatenate the product_number for each customer in it's own column only showing one row for each customer. The customer column is a varchar. I tried using STUFF and FOR XML Path, but I didn't get the results I was looking for.

It's giving me every product_number in reach in the PRODUCTS column, so instead of getting then products for each company, I'm getting the entire list or each product row.

```
SELECT customer_number
  ,first_name_initial
  ,last_name
  ,billing_address_line_1
  ,billing_city
  ,zip_code
  ,phone_number1
  ,email1
  ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + product_number
  FROM #TempS
  FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') [PRODUCTS]
FROM #TempS
GROUP BY customer_number
  ,first_name_initial
  ,last_name
  ,billing_address_line_1
  ,billing_city
  ,zip_code
  ,phone_number1
  ,email1
ORDER BY customer_number
```

I want it to read as below for each company for each row (I shortened for easy of reading).

Thanks in advance.

```
ROWID customer company  address city  zip_code phone_number email1   PRODUCTS
1     1255400  Company1 CAdd1   City1 10001    111-111-1111 e@c.com  01002, 09999, 09002 091111, 00005
```

[image: a busy cat]"

This did the trick.

```
SELECT customer_number,
       first_name_initial,
       last_name,
       billing_address_line_1,
       billing_city,
       zip_code,
       phone_number1,
       email1,
       Stuff((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), product_number)
              FROM   #tempsales t2
              WHERE  t1.customer_number = t2.customer_number
                     AND t2.product_number > ''
              FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') [Products]
FROM   #tempsales t1
GROUP  BY customer_number,
      first_name_initial,
      last_name,
      billing_address_line_1,
      billing_city,
      zip_code,
      phone_number1,
      email1,
ORDER  BY customer_number
```

Thanks.

Comment: condition is missing there in the select, thats why you are getting all the products, try this: STUFF((SELECT ', ' + product_number
  FROM #TempS WHERE fk_customer_number = customer_number
  FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') [PRODUCTS]

Comment: #TempS is a temporary tables, so no fk (I think that's accurate).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      ID INT ,
      cust INT ,
      prod NVARCHAR(4)
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 1, '0001' ),
        ( 2, 1, '0002' ),
        ( 3, 1, '0003' ),
        ( 4, 1, '0004' ),
        ( 5, 2, '0001' ),
        ( 6, 2, '0002' ),
        ( 7, 2, '0003' ),
        ( 8, 3, '0001' ),
        ( 9, 3, '0002' ),
        ( 10, 3, '0003' )


SELECT  t1.cust ,
        STUFF((SELECT   ', ' + prod
               FROM     @t t2
               WHERE    t2.cust = t1.cust
        FOR   XML PATH('') ,
                  TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    @t t1
GROUP BY t1.cust
```

Output:

```
cust    prod
1       0001, 0002, 0003, 0004
2       0001, 0002, 0003
3       0001, 0002, 0003
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the FOR XML criteria to get it to work. Full query above.

```
Stuff((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), product_number)
          FROM   #tempsales t2
          WHERE  t1.customer_number = t2.customer_number
                 AND t2.product_number > ''
          FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') [Products]
```